# The history of the past user names shows the change caused by a account merge: Is this the desired effect?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

I noticed that the history of the past names reports also the name changes caused by merging accounts.
I would expect it should show only the name changes done from the user; I imagine the purpose of that history is allowing the users to remember when the last change name has been done, and when the next change can be done. I don't see any purpose of showing the change caused by merging two accounts to the users, who could be confused (I imagine questions about the history showing a name the user has never used), and to the moderators, who already see when an account has been merged from the user history page (on the right side).

[image: screenshot]

Should merging two account cause a username to appear in the history of the past names? If the answer is yes, what is then the purpose of showing the history of the past used names?